# Show a website entry modal only one time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using [remodal](https://github.com/VodkaBears/Remodal#remodal) in order to show a modal on my website when someone access to it. This is how it works.

Load css and javascript:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/remodal.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/remodal-default-theme.css">
<script src="../dist/remodal.min.js"></script>
```

Define the modal itself:

```
<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal">
  <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
  <h1>Remodal</h1>
  <p>
    Responsive, lightweight, fast, synchronized with CSS animations, fully customizable modal window plugin with declarative configuration and hash tracking.
  </p>
  <br>
  <button data-remodal-action="cancel" class="remodal-cancel">Cancel</button>
  <button data-remodal-action="confirm" class="remodal-confirm">OK</button>
</div>
```

Show the modal:

```
<a href="#modal">Call the modal with data-remodal-id="modal"</a>
```

The thing is that the modal shows again and again everytime I enter the website.

Is possible to control this with cache or something that for each user the modal is shown only one time? This means that the first time the user access to the website the modal is shown, the user closes it, and the next time he refresh the website is not shown.

If it's possible, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using Cookie or localstorage...  How are you triggering the modal on page load? show us code?

Comment: Unless your users need to authenticate themselves, there is no good solution to this. You could use cookies or localstorage but there is no guarantee that these are actually persisted for a longer time.

Comment: I just force it by loading it via a `div` as follows: `<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal">content</div>`

Comment: Create a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ and share ur code sample.. we will take a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [remodal init with js](https://github.com/VodkaBears/Remodal#initialization-with-javascript), use that instead of the default function and before doing that check if a certain cookie exists, let's call it `seenModal`:

```
if (getCookie("seenModal") != "true") {
    //display the modal
    document.cookie = "seenModal=true"; // sets the modal-cookie
} else {
    // modal already seen
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        } 
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by entering a detail about user in mysql table..

just store the ip address of user and every time when user visits your site check for the ip address in table if it exists dont show modal and if not then show it..quite simple

Comment: you can do it by showing a modal and then set session variable and everytime check for session variable before showing the modal.

Comment: A session ID must be stored somewhere and be bound to a user, too. The question is about *how* to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that by creating a session variable and checking it. The session variable can be unset after certain time.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check for browser session only then you can use `localStorage` api provided by `HTML5`. But if you need universally for a user then you can save the `watched` flag in your `db`.